# Profile search/listings not working in 4.6.3/4?

Tags: profile

I updated to the 4.6.3 version of CiviCRM for Wordpress, and discovered that I'm not able to bring up a listing/search page via the 'Use Profile-Listings Mode' - I get taken to a page on the front-end of WordPress with a message 'No fields in this Profile have been configured as searchable. Ask the site administrator to check the Profile setup.'

The listings/search option seems to work fine in the Drupal installation I usually use, which is on 4.6.2, but the problem does seem to happen in both the Wordpress and Drupal demo versions of CiviCRM 4.6.4.

As far as I'm aware there's only two places to set searchability - on the field itself, and in the Profile fields edit list. In 4.6.2, I get the error message if I forget to set the Profile fields as searchable, but when I edit them to be searchable, the search listing works fine - as far as I can tell, I've not done anything different when trying it in 4.6.3.

Comment: can you give a link to the drupal or wp demo profile that is not working

Comment: The default setup on the demos doesn't have any profiles with searchable fields, but I'd been changing settings on the 'Name and Address' profile, ID 1, on both - the pages giving me the error message are http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/profile?gid=1&reset=1 and http://wp46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/profile&gid=1&reset=1 respectively

Comment: Looking at the same profile on my 4.6.2, it looks like the searchable fields also have their visibility set to public pages and listings, whereas the others are just set to User and User Admin - is that enough to make the difference? For the site I'm looking at this for, I wouldn't want to have the data publicly available...

Answer (score 1):

For a profile field to appear in the search settings, it needs to be:

1. Have the "is searchable" option selected
2. Have the visibility, set to: "Public pages and listings"

the latter is needed, so that everyone can see the fields and hence search on it.

Comment: Okay, so that explains what I was doing wrong. I'd assumed that 'Public pages and listings' meant it's accessible to non-logged-in users, which mostly I don't want. I know that I can control access to all profile listings in the access control, but how would I limit access to specific profiles? (i.e. I need a comprehensive search listings for the site's account holders, but may also want more limited information publicly available)